# Can't add 1 month to a moment.js date

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I've been trying to add a month to a date for a while now but I can't do it and I have no idea why:

My JSON:

```
{
      "module": "C Graphical Programming",
      "project": "Back To The Future - MyHunter",
      "start": "2020-12-14",
      "end": "2021-01-03",
      "bttf": true
    }
```

My code:

```
timeLineRaw.projects.forEach(element => {
        let timeLineEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        timeLineEmbed.setTitle("Test");
        let projectStart = moment(element.start);
        let projectStartPlusOneMonth = projectStart.add(1, 'months');
        if (moment(actual).isAfter(projectStart) && moment(actual).isBefore(projectStartPlusOneMonth)) {
            timeLineEmbed.addField(`${element.module} - ${element.project}`, element.start);
            channel.send(timeLineEmbed);
            db.get('projects').remove({project: element.project}).write();
        }
    });
```

The output of `projectStart` and `projectStartPlusOneMonth` from debugger:

```
Moment<2020-12-09T00:00:00+01:00> Moment<2020-12-09T00:00:00+01:00>
```

And if I try to add 1 month to actual date like this `moment().add(1, 'months')` this works...

Comment: Could it be because `add()` "Mutates the original moment by adding time": https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the variable in another reference of moment like this:

`moment(projectStart).add(1, 'months');`

moment needs to be referenced everytime that it's used.

Comment: Not really every time, .clone() would work here or you can run any of the display/query functions. As Hernán Alarcón mentioned, [manipulating moment dates](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/ will mutate the original.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var start= "2020-12-14";

var dt = moment(start);
var futureMonth = moment(dt).add(1, 'M');

console.log(futureMonth)
```

Comment: var is deprecated